# Custom meta box for custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to make a custom meta box.Now if anyone want to post he or she must have to fill the custom meta box.How to do it?Please show me the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add meta box in custom post type by using [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function

```
<?php
       add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_metaboxes' );
 ?>
```

Add Meta Box :-

```
<?php
     // Method for add metaboxes.
    function add_custom_metaboxes() {
       add_meta_box('meta_box_id', 'Meta Box title', 'your_callback_function', 'custom_post_type', 'side', 'default');
     }
```

Generating the HTML for the Metabox :-

```
<?php
 function your_callback_function() {
       global $post;
   // Code for your metabox fields goes here.
 }
?>
```

Some reference link :-
http://wptheming.com/2010/08/custom-metabox-for-post-type/
http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/